# Distorted cursor movements using HTML or JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a distorted or crooked mouse movement along a page (although the user is moving the mouse fine).

I don't want to seem crude, rude or mean, but i want to simulate a Parkinson's or arthritic patient trying to move a mouse across a web page.

How do i achieve this using HTML, JS/Jquery or even CSS? I even had a thought of using small grids along the page and having the mouse cursor snap to those grid edges to achieve the effect, but could not find any code relevant to this (or am i searching with the wrong keywords??)

I do not have any starting code so apologies if this may be a trouble to any of you, but I'd appreciate any help right now.

I am only looking for a browser solution, maximum browser compatibility is appreciated.

Comment: I had looked at the pointer lock demo, but it does not solve my query. I want to simulate the mouse pointer experiencing the tremor. I don't want users having to allow their browser to hide their mouse once the canvas has been clicked. The effect and experience needs to be seamless as the user needs to feel the effect without having to perform any operations. Although my usage is just about the same as the OP in the link you provided, I don't see any solutions in the thread that allow for this effect to be pulled off in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your `DIV`, CSS-hide the cursor using `cursor:none;`
- Create a .png Cursor image and move it (`left`, `top`) with jQ on `mousemove`
- Randomize the .png `margin-left` and `margin-top` using a `setTimeout`
  (to make the re-positioning smooth use CSS3 `transition` or do it with jQ `.animate()`).

Note: The script cannot know if the hand is still on the mouse ;)

```js
function rand(min, max) {return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;}

var $cursor = $('div img');

$('div').mousemove(function(e) {  
  $cursor.css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top:e.pageY
  });
}).hover(function(e){
  $cursor.toggle();
});

(function tremor(){
  $cursor.css({
      marginLeft: rand(-15,15), // arm tremor
      marginTop:  rand(-30,30)  // hand contractions
  });
  setTimeout(tremor, rand(50,100));
}());
```

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  background:#eee;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  cursor:none;
}

div img{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  transition: margin 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwMGA.png"></div>
```

Comment: the code works amazingly when i run the code snippet in SO. When i try it on at my end, it just shows me the grey BG and hides the pointer. What am i missing? But awesome work, just what i was looking for

Comment: @masmrdrr you're missing the pointer image

Comment: I've saved the image and calling it locally, still cannot see it... Can you please revise your answer with the full HTML code please, would be very helpful.. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: i've gotten it to work, didn't seem to work with the <script> tag in the header section... but thanks a ton very very helpful. 
would appreciate it though if you can mark up the question, as there are no similar questions and absolutely answers like yours online, even on SO.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that was an amazingly well done example.  I  wish I could up-vote that answer twice.